# integration GOOGLE map with OBIEE 12 c

Tags: google-maps, obiee

I am working in OBIEE 12C, I want to integrate google maps into OBIEE, I add it in mapViewer server and the map is displayed, but the problem is when I try to add it in BI analytics it displays the following error "MAPVIEWER-09001"

Does anyone know this error?

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the thing you get pre-configured exmaples for in the free ("free beer", gratis) SampleApp virtual machines: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html

You can just run it, check how it's done and use it for your own purposes.

Comment: thanks,but i didn't use the virtual machine,i created my own spaciale base