# Integration obiee 12 c with a GOOGle map

Tags: google-maps, obiee

I work with obiee 12c, could you say me where do you write this code for  javascript api,  I don't know where use them

```
<script language="Javascript" 
src="
http://localhost:7777/mapviewer
/fsmc/jslib/oraclemaps.js"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var mapview; 
  var themebasedfoi; 
  function initMap()  
  {     
    var baseURL  = "
http://sdolnx2.us.oracle.com:7777/mapviewer
"; 
    var mapCenterLon = 
-122.5
; 
    var mapCenterLat =  
36.5
; 
    var mapZoom      =  
2
;        
    var mpoint = MVSdoGeometry.createPoint(mapCenterLon,mapCenterLat,8307); 
    mapview = new MVMapView(document.getElementById("map"), baseURL); 
    mapview.addMapTileLayer(new MVMapTileLayer("
mvdemo.Google_map
"));    
    mapview.setCenter(mpoint);    
    mapview.setZoomLevel(mapZoom);     
    themebasedfoi = new MVThemeBasedFOI('themebasedfoi1','
mvdemo.customers
```

.............................................................

Comment: Possible duplicate of [integration GOOGLE map with OBIEE 12 c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026964/integration-google-map-with-obiee-12-c)

Answer (score 0):

a) duplicate

b) you apparently didn't read what I replied to the other thread